# Percy not capturing any snapshots

Tags: cypress, percy

I'm trying to integrate Percy and Cypress for one of my projects.
Sadly Percy doesn't seem to take any snapshots even though I'm calling cy.percySnapshot

```
This is output
\[percy\] stopping percy...
\[percy\] waiting for 0 snapshots to complete...
\[percy\] done.
```

This indicates that no snapshots are being captured during the test run. We've thoroughly reviewed our code and configuration, but we haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause of the issue.

We've ensured that our Cypress tests are running successfully, used unique snapshot names, and confirmed that the Percy configuration, including the project ID and token, is correctly set. We've also enabled debug output for Percy, but the logs don't provide enough information to diagnose the problem